# Window function to calculate a percentage based on value of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple small data set:

```
Player 1    W
Player 1    L
Player 1    L
Player 1    W
Player 1    W
Player 2    L
Player 2    L
Player 2    W
```

I am trying  to use a windows function to achieve this result which displays the player's win percentage:

```
Player 1 60%
Player 2 33%
```

I've tried this but it returns all zeroes

```
create table #t1 (
    player_name varchar(10)
    , win_loss char(1)
)

insert into #t1
values 
('Player 1','W')
,('Player 1','L')
,('Player 1','L')
,('Player 1','W')
,('Player 1','W')
,('Player 2','L')
,('Player 2','L')
,('Player 2','W')

select 
    sum(case when win_loss = 'W' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by player_name)
    / count(player_name) over (partition by player_name)
from #t1
```

Comment: You don't want a window function, you want a group by since you only want 1 row per player

Comment: And Google decimal result from int division in sql server.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use window functions here, just normal aggregates will work:

```sql
SELECT player_name,
       AVG(CASE win_loss WHEN 'W' THEN 1. ELSE 0. END)
FROM #t1
GROUP BY player_name;
```

If you windowed, you'd get the same row multiple times, which isn't what you want.